# Make all <li> same width as the widest

Tags: html, css, width, html-lists

I've got this menu wich is setup inline and has dropdowns.
The inner `ul` has a background.
Each dropdown `li` has a `:hover` that changes the background of the `li`:

```
<div id="navMain">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#nogo">Forside</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#nogo">1111111111111</a></li>
                <li><a href="#nogo">Link 1-2</a></li>
                <!-- etc. -->
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#nogo">Om Os</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-2</a></li>
                <!-- etc. -->
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#nogo">Link 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-2</a></li>
                <!-- etc. -->
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Problem is, that when one of the submenu `li` is longer than the others, it will only expand itself, and not the other `li` ofcourse.
This results in the `:hover` effect having different lengths.

So how would i make all `li` in each inner `ul` the same size as the widest one?

[Here you can find the CSS](http://forevertan.dk/_temp/eventfest/3/menu.css) if needed.

Comment: If you're only looking to support as low as IE8, you should look into **display:table-**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here. Notice I added a class to your menu **li**'s and that I added a body background to your css, because I couldn't notice your menus. Finally the trick is done by making the li elements 100% width

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

.menu li {
  width: 100%
}

#navMain {}

#navMain ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

#navMain ul li {
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navMain li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#navMain li a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

#navMain ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#navMain li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

#navMain ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-image: url(img/alphaBg.png);
}

#navMain ul li ul li {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}

#navMain ul li ul li:first-child {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#navMain ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navMain">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#nogo">Forside</a>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#nogo">1111111111111</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Link 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Link 1-3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Link 1-3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Link 1-3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Link 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#nogo">Om Os</a>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#nogo">Link 3</a>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

`li {display:block}` will make the list items as wide as the widest item in that parent container

Comment: Doesnt seem to work for me?
Here is an example
http://forevertan.dk/_temp/eventfest/3/test2.htm

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background: #ededed;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 720px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.menu li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%;
  float: none;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```