# How to change <li> to variable width on css dropdown submenu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, html-lists

I have a fixed width css dropdown menu and would like the slideout submenu to be variable width based on width of the text in the 'li'.

[image: variable width]

I tried this:
[Make all <li> same width as the widest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824232/make-all-li-same-width-as-the-widest)
but didn't work. All the examples I googled, talk about using float:left;width:100%;position:relative but everywhere I inserted it nothing changed.

Link to code: http://jsfiddle.net/Bqh9a/1/

My CSS is:

```
<style type="text/css">
.pipe {margin-top:4px;}
.li_hover {color: #002398;}
.bottom_li {margin-bottom:6px;margin-top:2px;}
ul#nav li .bottom_li:hover > a{background:#E0E0E0;}
ul#nav, ul#nav ul {width:300px;list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;position:absolute;z-index:9;border:1px solid #297BCE;}
ul#nav li li:hover > a{border:none;}
ul#nav li {position:relative;float:left;zoom:1; /*Needed for IE*/}
ul#nav li:hover > a{background:#E0E0E0;color:#297BCE;border-left:1px solid #297BCE;border-right:1px solid #297BCE;border-top:1px solid #E0E0E0;border-bottom:1px solid #E0E0E0;text-decoration:underline;}
ul#nav li:hover > ul{display:block;}
ul#nav li a{border:1px solid #FFFFFF;display:block;padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;color:#297BCE;font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial, Times New Roman, Tahoma;font-size:13px;text-decoration:none;}
ul#nav ul {padding-left:8px;padding-top:2px;display:none;position:absolute;width:150px;border:1px solid #297BCE;background:#E0E0E0;left:0;border-top:none;}
ul#nav ul li{background:#E0E0E0;color:#000;border:none;float:none;}
ul#nav ul li a{border:none;width:100%;padding:0;display:block;color:#000000;line-height:145%;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;} 
ul#nav ul li a:hover{border:none;width:150px;color:#297BCE;>}
ul#nav ul ul{position: absolute;top: 0;left: 100%;margin-left:-3px;display: none;}
ul#nav ul ul{padding-left:8px;position:absolute;width:150px;border:1px solid #297BCE;background:#E0E0E0;}
ul#nav ul li:hover ul{display: block;}
</style>
```

My HTML is:

```
<ul id="nav">
 <li><a href="/ueber_uns.htm">About Us</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Goals</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Press</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">2006</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2007</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2008</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
   <li class="bottom_li"><a href="#"><span class="li_hover">See all</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
<li class="pipe">|</li>
 <li><a href="/ueber_uns.htm">About Us</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Goals</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Press</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">2006</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2007</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2008</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
   <li class="bottom_li"><a href="#"><span class="li_hover">See all</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
<li class="pipe">|</li>
 <li><a href="/ueber_uns.htm">About Us</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Goals</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Press</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">2006</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2007</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2008</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
   <li class="bottom_li"><a href="#"><span class="li_hover">See all</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for any advice in guiding me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took your fiddle and added a new CSS class "snug" to apply for the list of years. Basically "snug" will let the list be as wide as its widest list element. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/2fc3W/1/

```
// the CSS

ul#nav ul.snug{
    width: auto;
}
ul#nav ul.snug li a{
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 6px;
    width: auto;
}

// the HTML snippet

<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="/ueber_uns.htm">About Us</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Goals</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Team</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Press</a>
            <ul class="snug">
                <li><a href="#">2006</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">2007</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">2008</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Impressum</a>
        </li>
        <li class="bottom_li"><a href="#"><span class="li_hover">See all</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
...
```

Comment: I looked at http://jsfiddle.net/2fc3W/ in Chrome but the years <li> still show the same width as the parent <li>?

Comment: Sorry I made slight error, man I think I need sleep...fixed now. Try http://jsfiddle.net/2fc3W/1/