# How to remove padding/margin from left in bootstrap navigation?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to center bootstrap navigation bar. The problem is that I can't remove default padding or margin from left. I tried with different classes but nothing works as I want. Navigation items should be ideally centered. This is my HTML & CSS, you may not see it but navigation items are little pushed from left.

```css
body 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

/* Header Start */

header
{
    display: flex;
    height: 10rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

nav ul li 
{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

nav 
{
    font-size: 21px;
}

#logo img 
{
    height: 220px;
}

/* Header End */

/* Navigation Start */

/* Navigation End */

/* Main Start */

/* Main End */

/* Aside Start */

/* Aside End */

/* Footer Start */

/* Footer End */

/* Media Queries Start */

/* Media Queries End */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width,initial-scale=1″>
    <meta name="description" content="opis strony">
    <meta name=”robots” content=”index, follow”>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
   
    <header>
        <div id="logo"><img src="img/logotest.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></div>
    </header>
    
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mx-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Articles</a>
      </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Reviews</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
    
    <main>
        
    </main>
    
    <aside>
        
    </aside>
    
    <footer>
        
    </footer>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you append a screenshot to visualize the problem (maybe use some auxilllary lines). Because as you pointed out in your post: I can't see the problem

Comment: @Uchendu check it out https://imgur.com/zysQL4u As you can see (for best view look at "article" nav item) image is properly centered but navigation is little pushed by padding or margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, your navigation is perfectly centered. I tried to visualize on the below image the distances to the border of the page. The colored boxes have always the same width.

[image]

As you can see, the `<ul>` tag containing the three navigation items is well centered. However, the list item for "Articles" is not. This is because the navigation is centered as one single element.

The alignment within the navigation could be achieved by assigning a specific with to each navigation item (`<li>`). I'd recommend to update one of your css rule:

```
nav ul li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

If you would like to adapt the width of your items to the widest element present in your list, checkout [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824232/make-all-li-same-width-as-the-widest) post.